# Jena; How to check A subClassOf B without iterating A super classes nor B sub classes

Tags: java, rdf, jena, owl

Let's have an ontology manipulated by Jena and two ontology classes (`OntClass`), A and B. Is there any method to check that

`A a subClassOf B`

without iterating through A super classes and checking if B is among them. Also without iterating B sub classes and checking if A is among them. I mean something like

`A.isSubClassOf(B)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place to check is the documentation.  (Actually, using an IDE that has some support for autocompletion would make this easy to find, too.)  In this case, the documentation for [OntClass](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html) has two methods that are exactly what you're asking for. It's not **isSubClass**, but rather [**hasSubClass(Resource)**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#hasSubClass(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource)). There's also [**hasSuperClass(Resource)**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntClass.html#hasSuperClass(com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource)).  For instance, to check whether A is a subclass of B, you could do:

```
OntClass A = ...;
OntClass B = ...;

A.hasSuperClass(B); // Does A have B as a superclass?
B.hasSubClass(A);   // Does B have A as a subclass?
```